# How to integrate Salesforce page to Native iOS App?

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, ios

In my native iOS app, some screens are to be rendered directly from Salesforce. For example my app displays the list of all contacts available in Salesforce in a UITableView. When user selects a contact to view its details the resulting screen should be a SF page. I wanted to do this because any changes to contact details page can be done on the server end & i need not to compile the app all the time.

Can this be done. Please point in some direction.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Given your user's current instance name and session token, you can construct a URL to any Salesforce web page and open it in a standard `UIWebView` (or `WKWebView`) without requiring the user to log in again. You can see [how I wrote this](https://github.com/ForceDotComLabs/ForcePad/blob/master/Accounts/util/SFVAppCache.m#L783-788) in ForcePad:

```
- (NSString *) webURLForURL:(NSString *)u {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/secur/frontdoor.jsp?sid=%@&retURL=%@",
            [SimpleKeychain load:instanceURLKey],
            [[SFVUtil sharedSFVUtil] sessionId],
            u];
}
```